# Unable to locate package gbedi-core

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

trying to install gdebi using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude synaptic gbedi-core
```

but I'm getting this error

```
Unable to locate package gbedi-core"
```

Comment: OK. I have posted it as answer.

Comment: Strange! You mentined:Trying to install "gdebi" (spell-right), but package-name "gbedi" used in command `gbedi-core` (wrong-spelling)!

Answer (score 1):

It is `gdebi-core` not `gbedi-core`.

So use following command:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude synaptic gdebi-core
```